Блок панелей в rc-picker
Работаю с библиотекой rc-picker все устраивает и подходит, но вот панель с десятилетиями не нужна:

В документации не обнаружил пропсов для блокировок конкретных панелей и такое ощущение что единственный способ это сделать, это взять библиотеку и засунуть напрямую в проект и поправить уже в коде что нужно, но не хотело бы таким заниматься.
Мб кто уже с таким сталкивался и может посоветовать другой способ как можно это сделать. Спасибо.

стилями скрыть. Хотя не очень понятен смысл - в этом и суть таких датапикеров - выбор даты по клику из списка.

@Arbery мне сама панель устраивает, по клику между стрелок меняются панели, по дефолту там дни как в обычном календаре, но есть еще несколько, месяцы можно выбирать, года по одному и вот эта с десятилетиями. Стилями не получится убрать, там нужно как-то функцию менять что бы не переключалась на последнюю панель.

По итогу добавил библу в проект и изменил её, других вариантов не нашел
